# Is it possible to catch java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError?

Tags: java, android, gson

com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson() is called in a try-catch block, but it still causes the following app crash though it happens **rarely**?

```
java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError: 
  at libcore.reflect.GenericSignatureParser.parseFieldTypeSignature (GenericSignatureParser.java:297)
  at libcore.reflect.GenericSignatureParser.parseTypeArgument (GenericSignatureParser.java:374)
  at libcore.reflect.GenericSignatureParser.parseOptTypeArguments (GenericSignatureParser.java:344)
  at libcore.reflect.GenericSignatureParser.parseClassTypeSignature (GenericSignatureParser.java:317)
  at libcore.reflect.GenericSignatureParser.parseFieldTypeSignature (GenericSignatureParser.java:289)
  at libcore.reflect.GenericSignatureParser.parseForField (GenericSignatureParser.java:218)
  at java.lang.reflect.Field.getGenericType (Field.java:177)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields (ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create (ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter (Gson.java:457)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField (ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields (ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create (ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter (Gson.java:457)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField (ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields (ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create (ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter (Gson.java:457)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson (Gson.java:921)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson (Gson.java:860)
```

Is there a way to catch java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError to prevent app crash?

Edit: the code is like the following:

```
try{
    ...
    foo = _gson.fromJson(bufferedReader, Foo.class); 
    ...
}catch(Exception ex) {
    ...
}
```

Perhaps my assumption that catch(Exception ex) catches everything is wrong.

Comment: Can you post code where you have mentioned try..catch() ?

Comment: Does `try { /* your code*/ } catch(/*your previous exceptions here*/ | java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError e ) { /*handle it here*/ }` not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hong, you can handle in the following manner.

```
try{
    ...
    foo = _gson.fromJson(bufferedReader, Foo.class); 
    ...
}catch(Exception ex) {
    ...
}
catch(Error err) {
    ...
}
```

Always remember, any error of type Error like `NoClassDefFoundError`, `NoSuchMethodError` are never caught in catch(Exception ex) block. However errors are irrecoverable. You can show some pop up message in your android app.

Comment: Thank you.  I assume the error causes the app to crash anyway even it is caught.

Answer (score 1):

**Try using this --**

```
try{

            //do your work here
        }catch (GenericSignatureFormatError e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

to avoid app crash.